# Xamarin iOS Build blocked by Avast antivirus - "Win32.Evo-gen [Susp]"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

I opened up a project which I had set aside for the past couple of weeks. The project was building fine back then, but now the antivirus throws an alert of "Win32.Evo-gen [Susp]" on Build or Rebuild. It basically prevents the creation of the exe. I've cleaned the project but it doesn't help.

The code that it doesn't like is the TouchUpInside event handler:

```
 UIButton btnCancel = new UIButton ();
 btnCancel.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (52, 5, 75, 30);
 btnCancel.SetTitle("Cancel", UIControlState.Normal);
 btnCancel.TitleLabel.Text = "Cancel";
 btnCancel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;
 btnCancel.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => {
  NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
 };
```

If I take out the last three lines of code, it builds fine.

I set the antivirus to ignore the project folder but now the antivirus is pointing to the XCode folders for iPhoneSimulator and CoreSimulator.

Was XCode infected and my antivirus got the updated virus signatures? I remember last week Apple was on the news about someone hacking the iPhone Developer SDK. I did get XCode directly from the app store...

Comment: Do you tried commented out the code that it doesn't like and see if the problem still exist? i.e. the build was fine but the antivirus still point to the XCode folders for iPhoneSimulator and CoreSimulator.

Comment: Maybe its related to Xamarin? I saw this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9691/xamarin-installer-with-win32-evo-gen-susp) but there is not answer yet...